# why new head and old head have the same sha id using git reflog?

Tags: git, version-control, git-reflog

i think these should be two different HEADS, so why they corresponds to the same sha value, that is 2aad8cb ...

```
git reflog
2aad8cb HEAD@{0}: checkout: moving from master to xxx_master   
2aad8cb HEAD@{1}: clone: from git@github.com:xxx/xxx.git
```

Comment: AFAIK clone copies a repo into a new dir, the HEAD should be identical to it's clone...

Comment: i don't use clone in fact, i just create new branch named xxx_master, then checkout that new branch...

Comment: It would appear that, at this point, both `master` and `xxx_master` point to the same commit (2aad8cb), so switching between them, while it does create reflog entries, doesn't actually switch which commit is checked out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you first create a new branch via `git branch newbranch` or `git checkout -b newbranch master`, `newbranch` will point to exactly the same commit as the branch point (whatever HEAD was in the first example, or `master` in the second). So it would be normal to see, for example, `master` and `newbranch` both having the same SHA. When you create a new commit on either branch, then that branch will point to the new commit, which will have the previous value as its parent (over-simplifying to avoid discussing merges, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

That is normal behaviour. The reflog keeps track of where head used to be and where branches used to be. So doing

```
git checkout master
git checkout experiment
git checkout master
git checkout experiment
git checkout master
git checkout experiment
```

will end up with

```
2aad8cb HEAD@{0}: checkout: moving from master to experiment
d8cbf4b HEAD@{1}: checkout: moving from experiment to master
2aad8cb HEAD@{2}: checkout: moving from master to experiment
d8cbf4b HEAD@{3}: checkout: moving from experiment to master
2aad8cb HEAD@{4}: checkout: moving from master to experiment
d8cbf4b HEAD@{5}: checkout: moving from experiment to master
```

in the reflog. You can see the values repeating.

Here I've used `git checkout -` a few times to switch between checking out a SHA-1 (detached  head) and master:

```
5016d9e (HEAD, origin/master, master) HEAD@{0}: checkout: moving from 5016d9e82379923c21268e73e4dad3122a5639ac to master
5016d9e (HEAD, origin/master, master) HEAD@{1}: checkout: moving from master to 5016d9e82379923c21268e73e4dad3122a5639ac
5016d9e (HEAD, origin/master, master) HEAD@{2}: checkout: moving from 5016d9e82379923c21268e73e4dad3122a5639ac to master
5016d9e (HEAD, origin/master, master) HEAD@{3}: checkout: moving from master to 5016d9e82379923c21268e73e4dad3122a5639ac
5016d9e (HEAD, origin/master, master) HEAD@{4}: checkout: moving from 5016d9e82379923c21268e73e4dad3122a5639ac to master
```

You can see that the same SHA1 entry repeats.